# Keeping track of factor levels without a dataframe

Tags: r, r-factor

Disclaimer: This project started out as someone else's code, and I'm sure there are non-optimal design decisions, but my hands are a little bit more tied than if it were my own project.

I have a machine learning algorithm that uses a trained model object in combination with a set of scoring data to create a data frame of scored data. The model object is a list with a formula and a data frame.

One of the roles of the model's data frame is to ensure that the scoring data frame has the same columns as those the model expects and that the factor levels of those columns are the same. To accomplish this, we store one arbitrary row of the training data in the `model$df` (data frame), because a data frame with no rows is forced to have no factor levels. We then use the somewhat kludgy line

```
scoring.set$df <- rbind(model$df, scoring.set$df)[-1, ]
```

which results in a scoring data frame with identical values but expanded factor levels. My understanding is that `rbind` forces levels in the factor variables of both data frames to be equal to the union of the levels in the two individual frames, so this does pretty much exactly what I need.

However, I'm sure that it's not the *right* way. Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance, and I'll be standing by to elaborate.

Comment: My thinking is that there's some way to store a list of variables with their desired factor levels, but I haven't been able to come up with it yet.

Comment: The line doesn't strike me as particularly kludgy- in particular, it's efficient in terms of lines of code. You could keep the levels as a list of vectors- would that be better?

Comment: Well, thanks! I guess it's not the line itself, but the storing of a data frame just for its factor levels. Can't decide if it's worth restructuring the code or not.

Answer (score 1):

Create sample datasets

```
set.seed(23452)

##create 5 variables with 15 levels and 5 variables with 20 levels
nrowd <- 100
full <- data.frame(
    replicate(5,letters[sample(sample(1:24,15),nrowd,replace=TRUE) ]),
    replicate(5,LETTERS[sample(sample(1:24,20),nrowd,replace=TRUE) ])
)

###the following code represents a process that creates a dataframe with variables 
###that have no more levels than full but may have fewer levels
scoring.set <- data.frame(sapply(full[sample(1:nrow(full),10),],as.character))

#factor levels are not the same
identical(sapply(full,levels),sapply(scoring.set,levels))
```

Here's how you might fix factor levels.

```
##make it so the levels of scoring.set variables have the levels of full
scoring.set2 <- data.frame(
    mapply(scoring.set,lapply(full,levels), SIMPLIFY=FALSE,
       FUN=function(scoring.var, full.level){     
        factor(scoring.var, levels=union(full.level,levels(scoring.var))) 
     }) 
)
```

The variables are still the same as before and now they have the same levels as full

```
all(
    mapply(scoring.set,scoring.set2, FUN=function(x,y){
        identical(as.character(x),as.character(y))
    })
)

    identical(sapply(full,levels),sapply(scoring.set2,levels))
```

The introduction of non-factor variables will complicate things but the general idea would be to subset to only factor variables by `factor.vars <- scoring.set[,sapply(scoring.set, is.factor)]` and then do something like `data.frame(fixed.factor.vars, scoring.set[,!sapply(scoring.set,is.factor)])[,names(scoring.set)]` to get everything back together in the same order.

Comment: Your first test looks tautological. And if you meant: `identical(as.character(full),as.character(scoring.set2))` .... it returns FALSE.